# Very slow python running time when trying to solve project Euler. Unsure if python or slow algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

The problem I am trying to solve is [problem 87](https://projecteuler.net/problem=87). The problem requires you to find prime triplets sum below 50000000. So far the code has been running for well over 10 min, enough time to write this.

> 28 = 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4
>
> 33 = 3^2 + 2^3 + 2^4
>
> 49 = 5^2 + 2^3 + 2^4
>
> 47 = 2^2 + 3^3 + 2^4

In my brute force approach I have optimised it to only check up to square,cube and quart values which are less than 50000000. I use a sieve to generate numbers up to 7071, which doesn't take very long.

```
def algo(primes_matrix):

    suma = []
    counter2 = 0;
    limit = 50000000

    # square max, primes_matrix[907][1] = 7041
    # cube max,  primes_matrix[72][2]   = 368
    # quart max, primes_matrix[22][3]   = 84

    for n2 in range(0, len(primes_matrix)-1):  # loop power 2
        for n3 in range(0, 72):        # loop power 3
            for n4 in range(0, 22):    # loop power 4
                
                add = primes_matrix[n2][1] + primes_matrix[n3][2]

                if(add<limit):

                    add+=primes_matrix[n4][3]

                    if(add<limit):
                        if add not in suma:
                            suma.append(add)
                            counter2+=1

    print "counter =",counter2
```

I only have started learning Python and so would have rather used C/C++ normally to solve this kind of problem as I believe it would perform faster. Is this the case? Or rather am I misusing some of Python's functions to make it run much slower than it should or have messed up somehow with my algorithm. Regardless I will try to reimplement it in C to see a difference. Thanks for your help!

Comment: At a glance, maybe you want to make `suma` a set rather than a list? `suma = set()` and `suma.add(add)`.

Comment: Yes, Python is slower than C for brute-force numerical problems. Yes, your algorithm is inefficient; I know of no Project Euler problem that has no Python solution within time limits.

Comment: If the code works with no errors, wouldn't [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) be a better place for performance and algorithm efficiency feedback?

Comment: Hey there! I rolled back your latest edit. Instead of editing your question to include a solution, you should either accept the answer that helped you the most or consider writing a self-answer. This is to clearly distinguish problem (question) from solution (answer). Thanks!

Comment: @Reti43 Code Review would be okay for this question, but this question is specific enough (asking about performance, specifically) to also be welcome on Stack Overflow. For more information read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this will be helpful or not, since I can't really test anything I'm about to say, but....

It looks as though you should place your

```
add = primes_matrix[n2][1] + primes_matrix[n3][2]
```

outside of the `n4` loop, since it is independent of it. No need to recalculate it 22 times.

---

It also looks as though `add` could be represented by a list that you iterate through, which means you might save time by using a list comprehension, instead of a nested for loop - i.e. instead of:

```
for n2 in range(0, len(primes_matrix)-1):  # loop power 2
    for n3 in range(0, 72):      
     ...
        add = primes_matrix[n2][1] + primes_matrix[n3][2]
```

try:

```
 add_list = [primes_matrix[n2][1] + primes_matrix[n3][2] for n2 in range(0, len(primes_matrix)-1) for n3 in range(0, 72)]
 for add in add_list:
     for n4 in range(22):
         ...
```

---

Maybe you want to replace `suma` with a set, instead of using a list. I think it should be quicker to add elements to a set, though I haven't timed anything like this ever.

---

Why not break out of the n4 loop once `add > limit` - i.e.

```
for n4 in range(0, 22):
   ...
   if (add >= limit):
      break
```

---

I think you only really need 1 `if (add < limit)` check in the `n4` loop

```
 for n4 in range(22):
    add+=primes_matrix[n4][3]
    if (add <= limit):
       if add not in suma:
         suma.append(add) # Or suma.add(add) if suma is a set - perhaps a variable name other than add would be good
         counter2+=1
    else:
      break #add > limit, so no need to keep looping through n4
```

---

OK - that's pretty much all I've got. I can see that some of this is echoed (preceded) in other answers, but HTH

Answer (score 6):

Not enough reputation to comment, but using a set "in" is a hash function with average lookup close to O(1) while the list "in" requires O(n). Python solutions for this problem can easily run for under a second. I'll list out a couple other optimizations to consider:

1. add = primes_matrix[n2][1] + primes_matrix[n3][2]
   should be outside of the for n4... loop as it's value does not change and you are recalculating it.
2. Whenever the add is already greater than the limit, break the loop instead of continuing to iterate.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to post helpful info and hints as an answer. Complete solutions to PE problems are discouraged.

Comment: alongside of using a set, there is no need to check pertenece to it, just add it and check the size in the end

Comment: @PM Is this considered a complete solution?

Comment: Definitely not! A complete solution is a fully working program, IMHO. However, be aware that even posting a complete algorithm description / pseudocode to PE and similar problems may attract downvotes from some users.

Comment: Hmm, okay thanks! I'll be more careful in the future